# Pre-programmed feature installs at apache karaf launch

Tags: apache-karaf, opendaylight, apache-karaf-feature

I am working on an opendaylight project that uses apache karaf. At the start of the program, I need karaf to have some features installed. Currently (and this works) I manually type this into the shell and the features get installed:

```
$ bin/karaf
Apache Karaf starting up. Press Enter to open the shell now...
100% [========================================================================]
Karaf started in 9s. Bundle stats: 409 active, 410 total

    ________                       ________                .__  .__       .__     __
    \_____  \ ______   ____   ____ \______ \ _____  ___.__.|  | |__| ____ |  |___/  |_
     /   |   \\____ \_/ __ \ /    \ |    |  \\__  \<   |  ||  | |  |/ ___\|  |  \   __\
    /    |    \  |_> >  ___/|   |  \|    `   \/ __ \\___  ||  |_|  / /_/  >   Y  \  |
    \_______  /   __/ \___  >___|  /_______  (____  / ____||____/__\___  /|___|  /__|
            \/|__|        \/     \/        \/     \/\/            /_____/      \/


Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown OpenDaylight.

opendaylight-user@root>feature:install odl-restconf odl-mdsal-apidocs odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-rest odl-openflowplugin-app-table-miss-enforcer odl-openflowplugin-nxm-extensions odl-restconf-all odl-openflowplugin-flow-services
opendaylight-user@root>
```

All this works. However, what I need is for this feature install to occur at the start automatically. I am aware there is a `shell.init.script` file and I have attempted to add this line to the botton of it:

`feature:install odl-restconf odl-mdsal-apidocs odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-rest odl-openflowplugin-app-table-miss-enforcer odl-openflowplugin-nxm-extensions odl-restconf-all odl-openflowplugin-flow-services`

But when I do this, I get the following error:

`/opt/opendaylight-0.11.0/etc/shell.init.script: Command not found: feature:install`

I am also aware that adding a featuresBoot element to `org.apache.karaf.features.cfg`

`featuresBoot = odl-restconf` (I shortened it to just one feature for ease of testing)

And I get this error:

```
org.apache.felix.resolver.reason.ReasonException: Unable to resolve root: missing requirement [root] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-restconf; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.10.0,1.10.0]"; filter:="(&(osgi.identity=odl-restconf)(type=karaf.feature)(version>=1.10.0)(version<=1.10.0))" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-restconf/1.10.0: missing requirement [odl-restconf/1.10.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-restconf-nb-rfc8040; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.10.0,1.10.0]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-restconf-nb-rfc8040/1.10.0: missing requirement [odl-restconf-nb-rfc8040/1.10.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-restconf-common; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.10.0,1.10.0]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-restconf-common/1.10.0: missing requirement [odl-restconf-common/1.10.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=odl-mdsal-broker; type=karaf.feature; version="[1.10.0,1.10.0]" [caused by: Unable to resolve odl-mdsal-broker/1.10.0: missing requirement [odl-mdsal-broker/1.10.0] osgi.identity; osgi.identity=org.opendaylight.controller.sal-binding-broker-impl; type=osgi.bundle; version="[1.10.0,1.10.0]"; resolution:=mandatory [caused by: Unable to resolve org.opendaylight.controller.sal-binding-broker-impl/1.10.0: missing requirement [org.opendaylight.controller.sal-binding-broker-impl/1.10.0] osgi.wiring.package; filter:="(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.service.blueprint)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))"]]]]]
```

So, I can tell that karaf is at least acknowledging the shell.init.script and org.apache.karaf.features.cfg, however I am clearly using the wrong syntax. I have exhausted my googling in finding the right syntax or finding examples of this. In fact, when I do google for this issue, I get advice along the lines of "use the shell.init.script" file, without an example or a link to documentation for how to use it.

For example, here is a similar question [script to run commands at start of apache karaf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29599037/1582712) but the answers really aren't full or complete. I don't know where to put the suggested commands, etc.

Anyway, I hope someone here can show me what specific command one uses in either shell.init.script or org.apache.karaf.features.cfg to accomplish this goal. (The goal being the equivalent initialization command to accomplish what I can successfully do manually as noted at the top)

Update:
I also tried this type of command:

`echo "feature:install odl-restconf odl-mdsal-apidocs odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-rest odl-openflowplugin-app-table-miss-enforcer odl-openflowplugin-nxm-extensions odl-restconf-all odl-openflowplugin-flow-services" | /opt/opendaylight-0.11.0/bin/karaf`

Which also didn't work. I don't get any error messages, I just know my restconf isn't working. Funny enough I did see all the features getting piped into the karaf shell, and the shell did seem to freeze up (seemingly like it was processing the command) but no-go after the cursor returned to me.

Thanks to @jamo as his answer lead me to the answer. I needed to only add this to etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg:

`featuresBoot = odl-restconf,odl-mdsal-apidocs,odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-rest,odl-openflowplugin-app-table-miss-enforcer,odl-openflowplugin-nxm-extensions,odl-restconf-all,odl-openflowplugin-flow-services, 25921329-8d07-420b-af13-94948bf1a78d`

I believe the trick was having the final `25921329-8d07-420b-af13-94948bf1a78d` which is some hex value that is in the default cfg file and I ensure it stayed in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we use the org.apache.karaf.features.cfg file exclusively in upstream ODL
system test. you can see it inside [this log](https://logs.opendaylight.org/sandbox/v), but specifically, here is what
it looks like for one of our yangtools jobs:

```
################################################################################
#
#    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
#    contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
#    this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
#    The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
#    (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
#    the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
#    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
#    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
#    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
#    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
#    limitations under the License.
#
################################################################################

#
# Comma separated list of features repositories to register by default
#
featuresRepositories = mvn:org.opendaylight.integration/features-test/0.12.1-SNAPSHOT/xml/features,mvn:org.apache.karaf.decanter/apache-karaf-decanter/1.2.0/xml/features, file:${karaf.etc}/5edc7e82-415e-4254-9731-f87670633bcb.xml

#
# Comma separated list of features to install at startup
#
featuresBoot = odl-infrautils-ready,odl-restconf, a3fb0299-0563-4506-b1a0-059253ab43b4

#
# Resource repositories (OBR) that the features resolver can use
# to resolve requirements/capabilities
#
# The format of the resourceRepositories is 
# resourceRepositories=[xml:url|json:url],...
# for Instance:
#
#resourceRepositories=xml:http://host/path/to/index.xml
# or
#resourceRepositories=json:http://host/path/to/index.json
#

#
# Defines if the boot features are started in asynchronous mode (in a dedicated thread)
#
featuresBootAsynchronous=false

#
# Service requirements enforcement
#
# By default, the feature resolver checks the service requirements/capabilities of
# bundles for new features (xml schema >= 1.3.0) in order to automatically installs
# the required bundles.
# The following flag can have those values:
#   - disable: service requirements are completely ignored
#   - default: service requirements are ignored for old features
#   - enforce: service requirements are always verified
#
#serviceRequirements=default

#
# Store cfg file for config element in feature
#
#configCfgStore=true

#
# Configuration of features processing mechanism (overrides, blacklisting, modification of features)
# XML file defines instructions related to features processing
# versions.properties may declare properties to resolve placeholders in XML file
# both files are relative to ${karaf.etc}
#
#featureProcessing=org.apache.karaf.features.xml
#featureProcessingVersions=versions.properties
```

You have a typo in your question with featuresBook, but I am guessing that's
just a typo on not your problem. It's very strange that feature:install works,
but not featuresBoot.

Comment: Hah yes that was a typo, I shortened the cmd. I am trying your suggestions for now, thanks for this.

Comment: It seems I'll need to figure out which specific repositories correspond to the features I am trying to install. I find that odd, in regular shell I don't need to specify any repositories so it doesn't make sense I need to do that here.

Needless to say, out of the box this doesn't work with my `featuresBoot` list.

Comment: Ah got it! What I needed was just the `featuresBoot` seciton, but I need to make sure it ended with 25921329-8d07-420b-af13-94948bf1a78d, so:

`echo 'featuresBoot = odl-restconf,odl-mdsal-apidocs,odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-rest,odl-openflowplugin-app-table-miss-enforcer,odl-openflowplugin-nxm-extensions,odl-restconf-all,odl-openflowplugin-flow-services, 25921329-8d07-420b-af13-94948bf1a78d' >> /opt/opendaylight-0.11.0/etc/org.apache.karaf.features.cfg`

Does the trick :)